# Web Application referencing another web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

How would you go about referencing one WEB application inside another WEB application.  I have Java Bean classes built using XSDs in Project A.  I want to use them in Project B (and other future projects - hence, I don't want to copy those classes into Project B).  I've put Project A into the Build Path and Deployment Assembly, but any time I run the B's Servlet using A's classes, I get the NoClassDefFoundError exception.

Why is that?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError indicates that classes are not present in runtime. Please recheck your classpath.

Comment: Yeah, under "Order and Export" (Build class path order and exported entries), I see my other project.

Comment: I have no idea what IDE you use and it does not matter. I ask about your deployment directory, that contains all necessary libraries. Your projectA jars/wars must be present there

Comment: jar the classes and place them in the /common/lib folder of your app server